# Overwriting variabes in Python

Tags: python

I wonder if overwriting variables makes any difference in python code.
for example this two codes (function argument is long string in both cases):

first:

```
def f(a):
    b=a.encode('utf-8')
    c=b[3:]
    return c
```

and second:

```
def f(a):
    a=a.encode('utf-8')
    a=a[3:]
    return a
```

I think in first case it will use more memory than in the second.

Comment: This is an extreme case of premature optimisation, it really makes no difference which snippet you choose here

Comment: In general, I'd prefer first form: 1) it allows explicit variable names and 2) future modifications where you realize you need one of the former steps at a later point are easier to make.

Comment: the content of `a` is probably retained outside of the function anyway, so no, you are not saving memory.

Comment: `def f(a): return a.encode('utf-8')[3:]` have shorter bytecode than both of your functions. ([`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis))

Comment: The only opportunity `f` would have to reuse memory is after the slice operation but before the return statement. Since `f` doesn't do anything in that interval, there is no effective difference in the memory used by either function. Once each returns, the same memory will be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: I wonder why my question is marked as unclear? it seems that everyone understood it because your comments answer my question :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No differences in the bytecode

Looking at the byte code, there seems to be no difference:

```
def f1(a):
    b=a.encode('utf-8')
    c=b[3:]
    return c

def f2(a):
    a=a.encode('utf-8')
    a=a[3:]
    return a


import dis

dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (encode)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('utf-8')
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  3          15 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
             21 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 BUILD_SLICE              2
             27 BINARY_SUBSCR
             28 STORE_FAST               2 (c)

  4          31 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
             34 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis(f2)
  7           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (encode)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('utf-8')
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  8          15 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
             21 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 BUILD_SLICE              2
             27 BINARY_SUBSCR
             28 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  9          31 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
```

### No differences in timings

Look at the run times:

```
%timeit f1('x')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 547 ns per loop

%timeit f2('x')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 570 ns per loop
```

When you repeat this, the values vary and one is tiny bit faster than other. So no difference.

### No difference in memory consumption

```
%memit f1('x')
peak memory: 66.32 MiB, increment: 0.02 MiB

%memit f2('x')
peak memory: 66.28 MiB, increment: 0.04 MiB
```